# How to share localhost using JetBrains's plugin "Code With Me"?

Tags: plugins, ide, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm trying to enable sharing of `localhost:5000` for all users, who joined my invite link.

I've already done this before by using Visual Studio Code with "Live Share" but I can't find a way how to do that in WebStorm.